# Difference in behavior of PluginWrapper.getDependencies() and UpdateSite.Plugin.dependencies

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can anybody explain the difference in behavior between these two APIs? The only thing that I can make out is that UpdateSite's dependency properties seem to mirror exactly the dependencies declared in each plugin's MANIFEST.MF file. The PluginWrapper APIs usually return more dependencies, but the nature of the "extra" dependencies returned is unclear. I thought perhaps it was transitive dependencies but tracing 2nd- and N-order dependencies of a few plugins by hand didn't seem to reflect that.

Here's an example console script:

```
final plug = 'nodelabelparameter'
println "Plugin-Plugin Dependencies for $plug:\n"

println 'PluginManager/PluginWrapper'
println '-' * 80
println Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin(plug).dependencies
println Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin(plug).optionalDependencies

println '\nUpdateCenter/UpdateSite.Plugin'
println '-' * 80
println Jenkins.instance.updateCenter.getPlugin(plug).dependencies
println Jenkins.instance.updateCenter.getPlugin(plug).optionalDependencies

println '\nUpdateCenter/UpdateSite.Plugin alt'
println '-' * 80
println Jenkins.instance.updateCenter.getPlugin(plug).getNeededDependencies()
```

And output:

```
Plugin-Plugin Dependencies for nodelabelparameter:

PluginManager/PluginWrapper
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[token-macro (1.9), jquery (1.7.2-1), parameterized-trigger (2.22;resolution:=optional), matrix-auth (1.0.2), windows-slaves (1.0), antisamy-markup-formatter (1.0), matrix-project (1.0), junit (1.0)]
[parameterized-trigger (2.22;resolution:=optional), matrix-auth (1.0.2), windows-slaves (1.0), antisamy-markup-formatter (1.0), matrix-project (1.0), junit (1.0)]

UpdateCenter/UpdateSite.Plugin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[token-macro:1.9, jquery:1.7.2-1]
[parameterized-trigger:2.22]

UpdateCenter/UpdateSite.Plugin alt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being answered in another forum by one of the main committers. In a nutshell, the difference in behavior is an artifact of a handful of plugins that were once bundled with core Jenkins. Other plugins can be presumed dependent on those plugins:

[Google Groups jenkinsci-dev response from Cloudbees' Jesse Glick](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-dev/_4-a66qSzOU/egyv8LKUBQAJ)